# Making an installer for an Office Add-in with a WCF service reference

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, office365, ms-office

I'm trying to build a series of MS Office add-ins that all link to with a WCF service. I built an installer using Wix on Visual Studio which installs the add-ins and the service host app.

When I try to launch the add-ins I get an error as follows:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'ServiceReference1.IAppCore' in the ServiceModel client configuration
>   section. This might be because no configuration file was found for
>   your application, or because no endpoint element matching this
>   contract could be found in the client element.

I tested the service with another app and it seems to be running perfectly, however I cannot get it to connect with the Office add-ins.

Has anyone come accross this issue?

Comment: The WCF code by default attempts to load configuration from `app.config` or `web.config`, which is not applicable to your situation (as it nows tries to read from Office's app.config), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/client-configuration You can convert the XML settings to equivalent code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for directing me towards an answer.

Actually, after deploying the add-ins I realized it was attempting to read the actual Office app's app.config file (i.e. Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE.config, etc.) instead of my own

The solution to this problem is, in the end, extremely simple.

In the Wix Product.wxs code the manifest registry entry needs to be prefixed with "file:///"

So in my case it fixed the issue by changing from this entry:

```
    <Component Id="Excel_Registry_Manifest">
        <RegistryValue 
            Id="RegKey_Manifest_XLS" Root="HKCU"
            Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\AddIns\ExcelAddIn"
            Name="Manifest"                   
            Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]ExcelAddIn.vsto|vstolocal"
            Type="string" KeyPath="yes" />
```

to this one:

```
    <Component Id="Excel_Registry_Manifest">
        <RegistryValue 
            Id="RegKey_Manifest_XLS" Root="HKCU"
            Key="Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\AddIns\ExcelAddIn"
            Name="Manifest"                   
            Value="file:///[INSTALLFOLDER]ExcelAddIn.vsto|vstolocal"
            Type="string" KeyPath="yes" />
```

I did this with all the add-ins and they're running perfectly now.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your problems could have been avoided if you used code-based configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Does your office add-in have `app.config` or `webconfig` file? The client invocation to the WCF requires the service configuration in the above file, like the below code.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:21011/" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService" contract="ServiceReference1.IService"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Then I create a call.

```
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
            var result = client.Test();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
```

If our client application doesn’t own an `appconfig/webconfig` file, we could use `Channel Factory` library to call the service.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-the-channelfactory
For instance, we could transform the above invocation to the below.

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
//given that we have known the service information, binding type, service endpoint.
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://10.157.13.69:21011");
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
            ChannelFactory<IService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(uri));
            IService service = factory.CreateChannel();
            var result = service.Test();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }

    //service contract is shared between the client-side and the server-side.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Test();
    }
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: The question is not how to create a web service.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev , I didn't create a web service, if the project doesn't own a configuration file, I just give an alternative plan, call the service with Channel factory.

Comment: The error mainly indicates that the add-in project tried to search the WCF configuration, located in the configuration file. If it is not RESTful style WCF,  the configuration should be automatically generated in those files. alternatively, we could call the service with Channel Factory. Thanks for your review.

Comment: I did have an app.config file, however, as @LexLi pointed out, because of this being an Office add-in it was trying to load from EXCEL.exe.config, POWERPOINT.exe.config etc. instead of my own config file

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev true, but it is about _how to fix WCF configuration issues_.  Abraham correctly supplies the code-based configuration in his example.  This is backed up by Lex's comment beneath the OP's question

Comment: @MickyD, the question was not related to the code-based configuration. Instead, the configuration file should be found by the add-in.

Comment: ...well no, it was how to solve a WCF configuration issue. _["The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)_. Config files have always been a hack lacking any form of _code-time validation_ and _subject to runtime errors_ in addition to the issues of _client and server config mismatch_. Config via code offers code-time validation and ensures that the same bindings are used by client proxies and servers. MS introduced many bad habits in its implementation of a SOAP framework config via files being one.

Comment: ...the problem raised by the OP could have been completely avoided had he followed best practices in WCF development, hence Abraham's answer.  It doesn't rely on Wix-trickery either